# Windows 10 scaling and blurriness issue

Tags: windows-10

A day ago, I suddenly started noticing blurry text & images on my screen, as well as weird scaling issues.

First of all, here is how my status bar and windows look like:

[image] 
[image]

(notice the battery icon, in particular).

All the texts now look different and blurry: in my browser, in terminals, everywhere.

In the browser, websites look different, smaller. To be sure this wasn't just an illusion, I measured a columned layout. Even though the browser scaling is set to 100%, when developer tools report a 1200px wide column, if I take a screenshot and paste it in Photoshop, I can see that it's actually only 970px wide.

I had a look at this question: [Windows 10 Font blurry 125% scaling](https://superuser.com/q/947391/107495) but the suggestions didn't really help:

- setting a custom scaling level of 125% does seem to fix the browser scaling issue, but it scales the status bar and other things to a scale that I was not used to (so this was not my previous value, for sure); also, why would I need to set 125% to make a pixel be 1px wide?
- checking "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" on every application is really not a solution

What could be the cause of this sudden change and how to revert it?

Comment: http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've mentioned this trick in my question, but I should *not* have to do this for every single application, as this was working perfectly before?

Comment: Is your display resolution set to the panel's native resolution?

Comment: @Benjamin Below the per application fix there is also a general tool that tweaks the DPI scaling method for everything.

Comment: @WesSayeed It doesn't need to be.. those are screen shots. They're at the same size as they are taken. It's a scaling problem.

Comment: @HTNW Are you talking about Display Settings > Change the size of text, apps, and other items?

Comment: Can you add a bit more information, such as if the monitor is a built in monitor or if its a stand alone monitor. If its a stand alone monitor, specify how it is connected to your computer.

Comment: @Benjamin I was referring to the link magicandre posted and is in your question. Along with the per app fix there is an actual program that runs the fix for you underneath.

Comment: Could the display resolution have changed to some non-standard value? It isn't exactly the same but my font sizes(for window labels, text, buttons etc.) have gotten "randomized" after updates twice, no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues are mostly solved now, after a cumulative update of Windows 10 released around 10 or 12 August 2016.

Everything looks perfect on my laptop's 3K display, and although I still *feel* like the text is sometimes slightly blurry on my external Full HD screen, it is much more crisp and readable, and the icons now look all right!