# What's the deal with the randomized alphanumeric characters at the end of the service name for select Windows services?

Tags: windows-10, windows-services, windows-server-2016

Can anyone please tell me the reason behind the randomized alphanumeric characters at the end of service name for some Windows services?

In particular:

CDPUserSvc_xxxxx
PimIndexMaintenanceSvc_xxxxx
MessagingService_xxxxx
OneSyncSvc_xxxxx
UserDataSvc_xxxxx
UnistoreSvc_xxxxx
WpnUserService_xxxxx

Comment: Where are you seeing this?

Comment: They are not randomized

Comment: I'm trying to ask the significance of the 5 alphanumeric characters that follow the underscore of each of those services - the x's are placeholders for the alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Such as CDPUserSvc_3951d.

Comment: The numbers are different for every different Windows virtual machine I create. On another VM, I am seeing the same service with a different alphanumeric sequence at end of it - CDPUserSvc_33c6b. The other services I mentioned - PimIndexMaintenanceSvc, MessagingService, OneSyncSvc, UserDataSvc, UnistoreSvc, and WpnUserService - will all end with the same alphanumeric sequence. I am just wanting to understand the significance of this alphanumeric sequence.

Comment: The random codes are for security reasons; see the answer of this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1182820/malware-or-strange-windows-services-behaviour