# How to disable OneSyncSvc_c523d on Win10?

Tags: windows-10, sync, services

Noticed that the sneaky Windows had turned on

Service name: `OneSyncSvc_c523d`

Display Name: `Sync Host_c523d`

service by setting it on **Automatic (Delayed Start)**.
Tried to switch it to **Disabled**, but it gives a pop-up window saying:

> Services
>
> ⚠ The parameter is incorrect.
>
> <kbd>OK</kbd>

Description says

> This service synchronizes mail, contacts, calendar and various other
>   user data. Mail and other applications dependent on this functionality
>   will not work properly when this service is not running.

So it would appear to be completely useless to me. (I'm not even logged on to Microsoft account, so the **Settings** > **Accounts** > **Sync your settings** tab is disabled for me - completely greyed out.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [easy way to disable the OneSync service](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3e7c2163-0903-4e0d-8dfd-4e79ee6c7523/unable-to-disable-onesynsvc?forum=ws2016) (and it's mirror) is to use the *Registry*.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Click *Yes* in the UAC dialog.
- Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OneSyncSvc_c523d`. **N.B.** MS may change the suffix for that key, so look for `OneSyncSvc_`, knowing the last few characters may differ.
- Change the value in `Start` to *4*, which means "disabled". N.B. if you are not an Administrator, or if the key is owned by *TrustedInstaller*, you may need to [change owner and permissions](https://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-take-ownership-permission-of-a-registry-key-in-windows/) on the key `OneSyncSvc_c523d` and its subkeys.

[image: One Sink Service]

Comment: Why is it showing "The parameter is incorrect"?

Comment: @LogoS, see the edit above: "MS may change the suffix for that key, so look for `OneSyncSvc_`, knowing the last few characters may differ."

Comment: Note that services with the alpha-numeric suffix are "per user" services.  To completely disable them, make the same change: setting `Start` to 4, in the service just above that has the same name, but no suffix.  That would be `OneSyncSvc`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to uninstall Microsoft OneDrive completely, go to

Programs -> Add or Remove Programs -> Microsoft OneDrive -> Uninstall