# Possible move ConnectedDevicesPlatform to another drive?

Tags: windows-10

The ConnectedDevicesPlatform @C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\ConnectedDevicesPlatform is continuously writing data to my SSD to D drive, is it possible to disable this service or move to another drive?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description " ConnectedDevicesPlatform is continuously writing data ", we can check if the data is associated with Bluetooth, or Printers & Scanners as well as music players, storage devices, mobile phones, cameras, and many other types of connected devices.

According to the following two articles, this service is used for Connected Devices Platform scenarios and corresponding files are all c:\windows\system32\cdp*.dll:

cdp.dll

cdprt.dll

cdpsvc.dll

cdpusersvc.exe

I think we can not disable this service and can not move the ConnectedDevicesPlatform folder to another drive.

For details we can refer to the following articles

[What is the CDPUserSvc service?](https://superuser.com/questions/1115769/what-is-the-cdpusersvc-service/1119760)

[Connected Devices Platform Service - What does it do?](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/58863-connected-devices-platform-service-what-does-do.html)