# started seeing this two services suddenly "CDPUserSvc_604aa" and "cbdhsvc_604aa"

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, services

I have just installed windows 10 20H2 on my desktop 3 or 4 days ago and below two services "CDPUserSvc_604aa" and "cbdhsvc_604aa" started showing suddenly, please check below screenshot
[image]

can someone please confirm are this two services are virus or official services from Microsoft ? because i have checked on other two laptops and i am not seeing this two services.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are Microsoft "Per-User Services" that use a random or pseudo-random suffix. They are "child copies" of the main service that, if I remember correctly, are created at login time. If you disable them they come back on reboot since they are "destroyed" when you log out and "recreated" when you log in.

[Microsoft: Per User Services in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows)

> Per-user services are services that are created when a user signs into
> Windows or Windows Server and are stopped and deleted when that user
> signs out. These services run in the security context of the user
> account - this provides better resource management than the previous
> approach of running these kinds of services in Explorer, associated
> with a preconfigured account, or as tasks.

Comment: Yes. If you sign out or shutdown with Fast Boot, they are recreated with a different suffix the next time you log in.

Comment: i have checked 4 other laptops with windows 10, why these two services not there ? i am just curious :(, they all have services mentioned in @john's answer - https://superuser.com/a/1597735/1023520

Comment: With respect to John, the Microsoft document I link to lists "Used for Connected Devices Platform scenarios" which is the wording john says is not correct. My services listing also uses this wording. The document also specifically lists the connected devices service as a per-user service. I do not see the clipboard service in their document but it was updated in 2017.

Answer (score 2):

I checked my 20H2 machine here and my production 20H1 as well. The services above are not running on my machines.

I have "Clipboard User Service" ,  not Clipboard Scenarios.

I have "Connected Devices Platform Services" , not Connected Devices Platform Scenarios.

I do not see this, and you do not see elsewhere.

So check for installed software, vendor apps and drivers, that might be doing this and check also for viruses with Windows Defender. Check and see if you have User accounts like this but I would not think so.

I trust this provides helpful information about this.

Comment: initially when i installed windows 10 few days ago at that time i was not able to find those services and today suddenly i am seeing those, strange. thank you for your answer