# Why is there no clipboard user service on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, services, clipboard

In windows 10, there is a service called the Clipboard User Service or `cbdhsvc` that manages the clipboard. In Windows 11, this service no longer exists

```
PS> Get-Service -DisplayName 'clip*'

PS>
```

The `dll` and registry key both seem to still be present, but why doesn't the service exist anymore?

```
PS> Test-Path $env:SystemRoot\System32\cbdhsvc.dll
True

PS> Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cbdhsvc


DelayedAutoStart   : 1
Description        : @%SystemRoot%\system32\cbdhsvc.dll,-101
DisplayName        : @%SystemRoot%\system32\cbdhsvc.dll,-100
ErrorControl       : 1
FailureActions     : {128, 81, 1, 0...}
ImagePath          : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k ClipboardSvcGroup -p
ObjectName         : LocalSystem
RequiredPrivileges : {SeImpersonatePrivilege}
ServiceSidType     : 1
Start              : 2
Type               : 96
UserServiceFlags   : 2
PSPath             : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cbdhsvc
PSParentPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
PSChildName        : cbdhsvc
PSDrive            : HKLM
PSProvider         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Comment: I assume the output of `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cbdhsvc` is from Windows 10 not Windows 11.  However, in my research the name of the actual service, should have a guid on the backside of the service name, is that not the case on your system?

Comment: @Ramhound I assume the guid you are talking about would be apart of the `Get-Service` output, but the problem (or I guess confusion) that I am having is that there is no output on my Windows 11 machine. I'm not sure where the guid should be if you are referring to the registry output though?

Comment: I do not see a clipboard service in the main services output. Much more clipboard settings info is in Windows 11 Settings than in Windows 10 Settings. So I have to assume this is yet another Windows 11 difference done in a different way.

Comment: @NicoNekoru - Read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1597730/started-seeing-this-two-services-suddenly-cdpusersvc-604aa-and-cbdhsvc-604aa)

Comment: cbdhsvc_56f4c  This user service is used for Clipboard scenarios  ---  (from my Windows 11 machine) ----  what I meant by Windows 11 doing things in a different way.   Thanks.

Comment: BTW @Ramhound - you should post as an answer as it answers the question very nicely.

Comment: @Ramhound the problem I had was that I could not find the service at all nonetheless the service name with any guid. I don't really understand what you are trying to tell me with that, yes the actual services on my machine are affixed with identifiers but a service that doesn't exist on my machine, the clipboard user service, would and does not have a guid.

Comment: @John ah I didn't search for `cbdhsvc`... it looks like that is running as intended on my Win 11 machine without the "Clipboard User Service" displayname. If you post that comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: In hindsight I should've looked for the full descriptions rather than just displaynames with `Get-WmiObject win32_service | Select-Object * | ? { $_ -match 'clip' }`

Comment: @John - I wouldn’t submit an answer I would just flag as a duplicate. Besides you already answered the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [started seeing this two services suddenly "CDPUserSvc\_604aa" and "cbdhsvc\_604aa"](https://superuser.com/questions/1597730/started-seeing-this-two-services-suddenly-cdpusersvc-604aa-and-cbdhsvc-604aa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Windows 11 machines, in full services:

cbdhsvc_56f4c This user service is used for Clipboard scenarios

It could appear a couple of different ways in different machines.  This from my desktop Windows 11 machine

[image: Clipboard service]

Comment: For some reason the name field on my machine shows `cbdhsvc_5387a` instead of the friendlyname but this did solve my problem.

Comment: My ThinkPad shows cbdsvc...   as well. Desktop is different

Comment: @NicoNekoru -  The guid is unique to each installation